# How to access request object in django-tastypie custom serializer?

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a middleware which modifies the request object based on the request

```
class MyMiddleware():
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path_info = "some special path":
            request.some_special_attribute = True
        return request
```

I have a resource using a custom serializer

```
class MyResource(ModelResource):
    name = fields.CharField("name")
    class Meta:
        serializer = MySerializer()


class MySerializer(Serializer):
    def from_json(self, content):
        if request.some_special_attribute:
            # modify the object and return
```

and the serializer must access the request object to return proper response object

Doesn't seem like there exists a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing the job of the Resource and the job of the serializer. You shouldn't be trying to implement any business logic in your serializer; It's only for converting between json (or other) and a native python data structure.

"and the serializer must access the request object to return proper response object". The *Resource* is for doing exactly that.

I'd recommend reading through the docs where it talks about hydrating and dehydrating data. http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#advanced-data-preparation

Here is an example from the docs where they've altered the request body based on an attribute in the request.

```
class MyResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        # If they're requesting their own record, add in their email address.
        if bundle.request.user.pk == bundle.obj.pk:
            # Note that there isn't an ``email`` field on the ``Resource``.
            # By this time, it doesn't matter, as the built data will no
            # longer be checked against the fields on the ``Resource``.
            bundle.data['email'] = bundle.obj.email
        return bundle
```